# jquery: draggable plugin -> remove drag behaviour from html5 video controls?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

im working with the jquery ui draggable plugin and i have an html 5 video element with "preload controls" that acts kind of buggy. I

```
$(".thumb").draggable();
```

if i drag the video by clicking on the video controls and i'm releasing the mouse again, the video still sticks with the mouse.

```
<div class='thumb video'><video width='260' height='200' preload controls>
```

i have no chance to release the video again if i started draggin it at the video controls.

any idea how i could fix this! i probaply should script my own video controls to fix this.

Comment: how come you decided to go with html 5. you dont need that app to work in ie and safari and many other browsers?

I would say your only chance of making cross browser draggable dropabble video players would be to go totally flash or silverlight

Comment: The move to HTML5 is admirable... maybe he wants it to be cross browser without a plugin? This sounds like the mouserelease event is being gobbled by the video element and not passed on to the draggable plugin. Try in different browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was tough. The video player really did stick to the mouse and eat those mouse up events. However, here's my workaround:

I check the internal Y coordinate of the mouse position during mouse over (adjustable value) and if it's outside of the range, I disable the drag-n-drop feature. I saw that the mousemove() event continued to fire when it was sticky, so that looked like an ideal access point for the logic:

```
$(function () {

    $('.thumb')
        .draggable()
        .mousemove(function (e) {
            var yAxis = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            $(this).draggable("option", "disabled", (yAxis > 150) ? true : false);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have had the same problem — i needed a draggable video player, that is draggable while playing, but as soon as it pauses, it collapses back to a thumbnail state.

as you found out the video player reacts on `mouseup` rather than `click` event. so it paused the video whenever i stopped dragging it, and i couldn't cancel the `mouseup` event.

the only solution i found was to overlay the video with a DIV that works as a handle for jQuery UI Draggable. `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove` events were used by Draggable, but `click` event i cought and paused the video.

this solution, however, doesn't work with overlayed controls - or you'll need custom ones.